# Can I put a single MySQl database in a different directory from the others?

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of databases in c:\xampp\mysql\data and am happy enough to protect them with standard MySql GRANT, or even no protection at all.

Now I intend to make a database which *must* remain private. I don't trust my mastery of MySql security and worry about possible reverse engineering, etc.

Can I put the database in a TrueCrypt volume and specify the path to it when connecting?  The --database argument looks interesting, but I can't find enough information.

If I want to do it programatically, an I specify the path in the connect string?

Comment: Realistically, which do you think is more likely - someone gaining access to your MySQL database (which should have access to the data no matter what you do to the physical files), or someone gaining access to your file system?  I'd be more worried about the former, myself.

Comment: Personally I trust TrueCrpt above all else, but, or course, ymmv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any way to do this in the way you specify.

However it is possible to run more than one instance of MySQL on a single machine. Each server can (must) then have a seperate data directory.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html

As each server must communicate on a different port, you would select the required database by the port.

Comment: +1, as this is the only way to get what Mawg asked for. However, I do think Mawg is asking the wrong question here.

Comment: +1 and the answer. Yes, I am probably asking the wrong question, but I am no MySql gurur and I do know that doing this will make me secure.

Comment: No, the point is, doing this will *not* make you more secure.  I believe that all it is actually doing is giving you a false sense of security.  No matter what you do to secure the files themselves, anyone with access to the MySQL service will have a way to get at the data.

Comment: I have to agree that this will not really give you any greater security as the public port to MySQL is a public port. To really secure things, you must understand MySQL's security set up.

Comment: Agreed. Unless you're concerned about people physically accessing the machine, then securing remote access would be more profitable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.

When you start the MySQL Server, you can specify `--datadir`, but this won't solve your requirements.

Curious why you don't trust MySQL's Permissions system though?

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is a good possibility.  I won't be acceessing this d/b often, so a restart is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the database on a TrueCrypt volume, but you can't specify the path as a parameter for a connection. The path is a configuration option either when setting up the server, or creating tables.